Why is int type not able to convert to list directly?
Why is casting not supported in int -> list conversion?
num = 2
output = list(num)
print(out)

Result:
output = list(num)
          ^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

The case of int -> str and str -> list is workable because string is iterable:
num = 2
output = list(str(num))

Result:
['2']

Alternatively:
num = 2
output = [num]
print(output)  # it worked.

Why is int object not able to convert to list in Python using casting and what is different between using list() and []?

For exactly the reason it tells you. list(...) and [...] only appear the same because a string is an iterable of strings and yours has a length of 1; contrast list("abc") and ["abc"].

list() requires that the value be a sequence.  That's just how it works.

@JohnGordon an iterable, as the error says (all sequences are iterable, but not vice versa).

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please refer to this documentation

The list() function takes an iterable collection of values, iterates through the elements, collecting them all into a list of those values. So the argument has to be an iterable value of some kind, such as a tuple, string, dictionary, or generator. It's similar to:
def list(it):
    result = []
    for item in it:
        result.append(item)
    return result

An integer is not a collection of values, it's just a single value. You can't iterate over it with for item in num:.
A string is iterable, so if you convert the integer to a string with str(num) you can iterate over its characters.
output = [num]

doesn't try to iterate over num. It just uses it as the single element in the new list.
Consider the difference here:
abc = "abc"
output1 = list(abc)
output2 = [abc]
print(output1, output2)

This will print:
['a', 'b', 'c'] ['abc']

The list() function makes each item in the input collection into a separate element of the result.
